# Java Try-Catch Issue with Scanner

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I have a code for handling error ArithmeticError in Java.. But there is a compilation error of ElementNotFound when I use the variables n and m in my code ..
Code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Abc {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int m = sc.nextInt();
            if(m < 0 || n < 0){
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            }
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid!");
        }
        int i = 1,k=0;
        while( (i * i )  <= (m + n)){  // Error in this line m and n not found
            if((i * i) == (m + n)){  // Error in this line also
                k = 1;  
                break;
            }
            i += 1;
         }
         if(k == 1){
             System.out.println(i);
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("-1");
         }
   }
}
```

On removing the try catch block, the code compiles and runs as intended..

Error:
error: cannot find symbol
  while( (i * i )  <= (m + n)) ^
  symbol:   variable m
  location: class Abc

Abc.java:32:  error: cannot find symbol
  while( (i * i )  <= (m + n)) ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class Abc

Abc.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                if((i * i) == (m + n))
                               ^
  symbol:   variable m
  location: class Abc

Abc.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                if((i * i) == (m + n))
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class Abc

4 errors

Comment: This code doesn't have any error. Please provide a [mcve] and the full error message.

Comment: Still missing the error/exception details.

Comment: `m` and `n` are local variables inside try

Comment: since `m` and `n` are declared inside the try block, they are not known outside - just remove the try-catch - you are catching the exception (that you are generating/throwing) but going on as nothing have happened

Answer (score 1):

Initialize m and n outside of try-catch blog. m and n out of scope right now.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    try{
        n = sc.nextInt();
        m = sc.nextInt();
        if(m < 0 || n < 0){
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid!");
    }
    int i = 1,k=0;
    while( (i * i )  <= (m + n)){  // Error in this line m and n not found
        if((i * i) == (m + n)){  // Error in this line also
            k = 1;  
            break;
        }
        i += 1;
     }
     if(k == 1){
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("-1");
     }
```